# Inputting double type numbers with "." returning error. It works with ","

Tags: java, double

When I input for example firstnum = 1,5; secondnum = 3,2 it returns sum. But when I input numbers with "." instead of "," it returns error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Variables.main(Variables.java:11)
```

Can someone explain me that? In tutorial i watch guy did exacly the same program and it was returning sum even if he used double numbers with ".".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Variables 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanny = new Scanner(System.in);
        double first_number, second_number, answer;
        System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
        first_number = scanny.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
        second_number = scanny.nextDouble();
        answer = first_number + second_number;
        System.out.println(answer);

    }

}
```

Comment: what is your locale/what decimal separator is in use where you live?

Comment: huh thats interesting, i've checked wiki and it says in poland we use comma, i didn't even know that's different in different countries. so, how do eclipse know that in poland we use comma and not point?

Comment: Your operating system has a language. And the Java Runtime will simply use that bit of information. Run your software e.g. from an english Ubuntu Live CD and it will accept `3.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Locale/i18n, your machine and his machine has different locales.
The JVM use your system locale as default.
To change you can do:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
```

In this case, your decimal separator will be ","

If you set locale to:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Then you need to use "."

You can read more about internationalization/i18n on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

Comment: This will set locale in entire virtual machine which can be risky. It is better to limit this change to place where it is needed. In this case it can be changed for current Scanner instance by invoking `scannerInstance.useLocale(newLocale)`.

Comment: @Pshemo good point! But i think that change just the scanner locale doesn't make sense because you need your entire app with a locale configuration, why just scanner? and the others things? I think that he could use another resource like Dates or whatever that would require i18n too.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because your computer is set to a locale that uses a comma as the delimiter for a decimal in floating point computations. The person who made the tutorial could have had a locale set to the United States, in which case it's a "."

In Britain and other European countries (I'm pretty sure), the delimiter is ","

Comment: Britain also uses `.` as a decimal separator. Wiki has a nice little map of various different decimal separators across the globe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system

Answer (score 3):

The use of a comma or a dot as the decimal separator depends on the current locale of your JVM which depends on the host configuration.

You can change it using [`Scanner#useLocale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale)):

```
scanny.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the country your in and locale you use. In US I get the same error if I use comma instead of dot. You may have to use "comma" or set the locale properly. See below decimal seperator by country.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

Answer (score 2):

You can set this information if you use DecimalFormat using [getDecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#getDecimalFormatSymbols--) and setDecimalFormatSymbols instead of using Scanner directly